# PhpStorm navigate to -> file search only for Twig files

Tags: phpstorm

I have strange problem connecting with PhpStorm IDE. I use version `2016.3.2 Build #PS-163.10504.2`.

I love using <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> for searching files which I need to override. I have 2 project (one new, one old) and in old file searching works fine and in new search only for twig files and nothing else.

[image]

Is there any configuration I need to change?

Comment: Check your filter -- you may have selected to list Twig files only (the blue Funnel icon on that popup -- right top side)

Comment: @LazyOne I've already checked, all of them are enabled.

Comment: Please use `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE then -- *usually* helps in such cases

Comment: @LazyOne Invalidate caches helps. Thanks a lot! I spent 2 hours on trying to getting this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check filter -- the blue Funnel icon on the right top corner of that popup -- you may have selected to list files of certain types only.

Otherwise -- try universal `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- it usually helps in such "suddenly stop working" situations.